# JavaScript approach for creating a singleton or keep variable reference

Tags: javascript

Sometimes techniques like this is used to keep variable reference or create singleton. In this way we will call createVariable one time only. 
What are the pros and cons of this approach?

```
function createVariable() {
    // usually here may be some long asynchronous task
    // 
    return true;
}

function useVariable() {
    if(!useVariable.someVar) {
        useVariable.someVar = createVariable();
    }

    // do something with useVariable.someVar 
}

// we will call useVariable several times. 
// The idea is to call createVariable 
// one time only. 
useVariable();
useVariable();
useVariable();
```

I am grateful to all ideas and recommendations. I don't want to create a singleton. Just want to keep variable reference on function level. Without 
pollute the global scope.

Comment: This definitely wont work with boolean variables. Check if variable is undefined instead: (typeof useVariable.someVar === 'undefined')

Comment: I would expect the call to createVariable to return a new or stored var, not useVariable to need to track

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the pros and cons of this approach?

The *approach* is okay, although I question the need for it as higher-level design question.

The *implementation* has a couple of issues:

1. If `someVar` contains a *falsey* value, you'll recreate it when you shouldn't. To check if you've previously created it, use `if(!useVariable.hasOwnProperty("someVar")) {` rather than `if(!useVariable.someVar) {`.

   The falsey values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `null`, and of course, `false`. (All other values are "truthy".)
2. Functions have some built-in properties, both their own (`name`, `length`) and ones they get from their prototypes (various methods, mostly). So if your variables have names like `name`, `length`, `call`, and so on, you'll mistakenly think you've created them when you haven't as `createVariable` will already have those properties with truthy values (in your `createVariable` case). You can work around that by adding a prefix of some kind, or using a separate object as a map (although objects inherit properties, too, so you'd still probably need a prefix), or if you were using ES2015+, you could use a `Map`.

You've said you only want to create the variable once and "not pollute the global scope" (which is a good thing to avoid). I do that by just wrapping my code in a scoping function:

```
(function() {
    var someVar = createSomeVar();

    // My other code here
})();
```

That keeps the global namespace untouched, and creates only a single copy of `someVar` without the need for any particular plumbing.

Comment: I want to avoid a scoping function. The idea of question is just to collect opinions about the approach. Thank you!

Comment: @GeorgiNaumov if your purpose "is just to collect opinions", then your question is probably off-topic for Stack Overflow. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would create a singleton (from http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern):

```
var Singleton = (function () {
    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new Object("I am the instance");
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();
```

then use it like this

```
var instance1 = Singleton.getInstance();
var instance2 = Singleton.getInstance();

//You can see here that they are indeed the same instance
alert("Same instance? " + (instance1 === instance2));
```

NOTE: this took five seconds to find via Google: http://dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern

Comment: NOTE: this took five seconds to find via Google: http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern

Comment: How does "This is how you create a singleton" answer the question "What are the pros and cons of this approach?"

Comment: I added it to the answer. But what is you question really asking? Are you asking what the pros and cons of the Singleton design pattern are?

Comment: The question is edited.  I don't want to create a singleton. Just want to keep variable reference on function level. Without pollute the global scope. The idea is to call createVariable  one time only.